# Changing color of <a> in HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a help in changing color of  element by input. I changed a normal text yet but I dont know how to change this type by html Input. Any solutions?

HTML + JS

```css
function changeColor() {
  let color=document.getElementById('barvaStranky').value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor=color;
}

function changeColor2() {
  let color=document.getElementById('barvaTextu').value;
  let color2=document.getElementById('proklikKviz').value;
  document.body.style.color=color;
  document.color2.color=color;
}
```

```html
<label for="barvaStranky">Barva stránky:</label>
<input type="color" id="barvaStranky" value="#43A78B">
<input type="button" id="colorButton" value="Změň barvu" onclick="changeColor()">
<br><br>
<label for="barvaTextu">Barva textu:</label>
<input type="color" id="barvaTextu" value="#FFFFFF">
<input type="button" id="colorButton2" value="Změň barvu" onclick="changeColor2()">
<br><br>
<ul style="list-style-type: none; font-size: 25px;">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html" id="proklikKviz">Testovací kvíz</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check this https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/ExWOLWv

Comment: ```let color2 = document.getElementById('proklikKviz');``` (Don't add value in this line) and add the color like ```color2.style.color = color;``` ..

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear. since I dont know what do you want to ask, I assume two cases, one is changing color or  and second is `document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;` is not working.

in this case, solution for first case is

```
a{
   color:inherit
}
```

and solution for second problem is to use the function `setProperty`.

```
document.body.style.setProperty('background-color','#000')
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you do know how to change the color of 'ordinary' text but what you are wanting (I think) is to change the color of the inside an a tag element.

Browsers tend to overrule the 'normal' text color setting for such links and color them (usually blue) and underline them so you need to be more specific in what it is you are changing - or add that new code as well as your original code:

```
document.body.querySelector('ul li a').style.color=color;
```

In this snippet I've just changed the setting for the second color input but of course you can change, or add, it for the first one too.

```js
function changeColor() {alert();
  let color=document.getElementById('barvaStranky').value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor=color;
}

function changeColor2() {
  let color=document.getElementById('barvaTextu').value;
  let color2=document.getElementById('proklikKviz').value;
  document.body.querySelector('ul li a').style.color=color;
  //document.color2.color=color;
}
```

```html
<label for="barvaStranky">Barva stránky:</label>
<input type="color" id="barvaStranky" value="#43A78B">
<input type="button" id="colorButton" value="Změň barvu" onclick="changeColor()">
<br><br>
<label for="barvaTextu">Barva textu:</label>
<input type="color" id="barvaTextu" value="#FFFFFF">
<input type="button" id="colorButton2" value="Změň barvu" onclick="changeColor2()">
<br><br>
<ul style="list-style-type: none; font-size: 25px;">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html" id="proklikKviz">Testovací kvíz</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```